# Add code behind files to a SharePoint App Project (provider-hosted)

Tags: 2013, development, app

Let's first describe my work context:
I am working on SharePoint 2013 on-premise

I have created an App for a SharePoint 2013 Solution using Visual Studio 2012 with provider-hosted option. Two projects have been added: a SharePoint app project and a Web Application Project.

If I add an aspx page to the SharePoint App Project, the `aspx.cs` page is not generated.

Is there a way to add code behind files to my SharePoint App Project?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not have C# code in your App-project, only in you Provider Hosted project